# How can I secure a password from the client side? Is it needed or HTTPS/SSL will suffice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, password-encryption, password-hash

I am using encryption on the server-side to store passwords in the database. My concern is for the client-side. Do I need to use any encryption technique or HTTPS/SSL is sufficient to rely upon?

Comment: I don't think the password hashing (if used) should be performed on the server at all. It is safer if the client hashes the password and pass its hash to the server rather than passing its raw value (unless the server needs it as it is for some reason - if it is not just for input checking).

Comment: @dedecos but if you do it on the client, your hashed password becomes your password.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8596/https-security-should-password-be-hashed-server-side-or-client-side

Comment: @John Yes, but you create a layer of abstraction around the user password. An intruder will never have the raw password by e.g. sniffing the network. As OP was concerning about security I thought it could be a valid point.

Comment: @dedecos But if someone is in a position to sniff the network, to the extent that TLS doesn't help (i.e. they have installed their own root certificate on the target machine), then they're also in a position to perform a MITM attack such that the page served no longer hashes the password and they just receive the raw one. And, if the server doesn't further hash the password (e.g. as another iteration of PBKDF hashing with a different salt) then if somebody compromises the database, they can access any account in the system with a barely modified client.

Comment: @John Yeah that make sense. So we are talking that hashing or other method to hide the original password should be performed at both client and server sides?

Comment: @dedecos No he means there is no need to hash it on the client. If you encrypt the _channel_ (e.g. by using HTTPS) then everything which is sent from the client to server is encrypted whilst in transit. Therefore there's no need to encrypt or hash individual pieces of data within it.

Comment: @dedecos and if someone has compromised the HTTPS connection then chances are they can also compromise the server, so all bets are off

Comment: @ADyson what are the benefits of doing the hashing or masking of the password at server side and passing it with its original value as it leaves the client? Can you tell me one good reason to do not hash the password at client-side?

Comment: @dedecos the benefit of hashing the password on the server side (and hashing it correctly) is that if somebody somehow gets a dump of your database, they a) don't know what the user's plain text password is (which would grant them access to their account on your site, and any site where the user reused the email/username and password combo) and b) they can't tell if any two users have the same password. In a client hashing scenario, a compromised database would have all the info required to login to the service as the victim.

Comment: @John but I suggested to hash or mask the password in both client and server sides.

Comment: @dedecos This is 100% my opinion now, but provided the server is correctly hashing passwords, etc. and the client/server connection has TLS (and with Let'sEncrypt, there's no excuse not to), there's little benefit to hashing the password client-side. Given that Javascript doesn't natively provide hashing methods, it means your website footprint has to be larger to support it.

Comment: @John got it. Dependent on scenario but valid point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say A valid SSL certificate is Enough.

> the client side hash should be treated as if it was the user's direct
>   password. It provides no more or no less security on the server than
>   if the user had directly given their password and should be protected
>   as such.
>   [more info...](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/53594/why-is-client-side-hashing-of-a-password-so-uncommon)